# Homebrew not installing?

Tags: homebrew

So, I've googled and googled and googled for months and can't find anyone else having this error. So, I'm going to ask here (even though my questions keep getting closed and deleted). This also happens when I try to use any of Homebrew's `install` commands. It also happens when I try to install git.

I went onto the Homebrew wiki and found this command:

```
mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

I got the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1e/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
  /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1e/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib: stat() failed with errno=13
```

I ran this command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

And got the exact same error.

I have XCode Command Line Tools installed, and have the latest version of XCode.

I need help with this because I wish to install Ninja-IDE on Mac.

Thanks! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Nor is this a python question.

Comment: Hold on. Off topic? How? And all my other ones have been valid questions. I asked why Eclipse said it was re-indexing and provided all relevant information that I could, and it was closed. I asked how to do something in LibGDX a while ago, and got banned from StackOverflow. But why is this happening? It doesn't answer my question.

Comment: See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more info on that. I said _slightly_, because it's not related to programming. But I didn't vote to close or anything because I myself prefer to have questions like this one on SO.

Comment: I never did get any help on this :|

Comment: It IS on topic on if we consider that Homebrew is used to install programming tools, apps and libraries that are required to develop successfully on Mac OS. Yeah, it can be used to install things that are not related to development, just as vim, emacs, and sublime can be used to edit files that are not source code, but there's no question that those editors are on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed this issue myself. I had to wipe my MacBook Pro, and then it worked. Good luck, and hope this helps anyone else who has had this issue!